# gganimate creating duplicate legend and caption

Tags: r, ggplot2, gif, animated-gif, gganimate

I have created an animated plot .`gif` using `gganimate`. The problem is that the output has duplicated legend and caption and I don't know what's causing it.

The legend should be in bottom and the caption should be on the bottom left part of the plot. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Reproducible example:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(viridis)

t <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, frame = year)) +
        geom_point() +
        scale_color_viridis(name="Continent", discrete=TRUE) +
        scale_x_log10() +
        theme_void() + 
        theme( legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "vertical", legend.title.align = 0) +
        labs(title = "Year: ") +
        labs(caption = " Caption test") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.05)) +
        theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, color="gray40", size=10)) 



gganimate(t, "output_test.gif")
```

[image]

UPDATE [24-03-2017]: David Robinson, the author of `gganimate` confirmed to me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/drob/status/844561180559654914) that this strange behavior is caused by a bug that should be fixed sometime soon.

In the mean time, @hrbrmstr's solution looks like a good work around. Another alternative is to use an older version of `gganimate`, which can be installed like this:

```
  library(devtools)
  install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate", ref = "26ec501")
```

Comment: You also need `library(viridis)` in your reproducible example.

Comment: It's a quirk of the gif export process: it works fine for mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it outside of `gganimate`.

Cleaning up the files is an exercise left to the reader :-)

```
library(gapminder)
library(viridis)
library(magick)
library(tidyverse)

td <- tempdir()

years <- sort(unique(gapminder$year)) 

pb <- progress_estimated(length(years))

map_chr(years, ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

  filter(gapminder, year == .x) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_viridis(name="Continent", discrete=TRUE) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    labs(title = sprintf("Year: %s", .x)) +
    labs(caption = " Caption test") +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 2), shape = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
    theme_void() + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "vertical", legend.title.align = 0) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.05)) +
    theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, color="gray40", size=10)) -> gg 

  fil <- file.path(td, sprintf("%04d.png", as.integer(.x)))

  ggsave(fil, width=5, height=3, gg)

  fil

}) %>% 
  map(image_read) %>% 
  image_join() %>% 
  image_animate(fps=2, loop=1) %>% 
  image_write("animated.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: nice alternative. Thanks!

Comment: One minor issue with this output is the legend is not identical across all images - gganimate does ensure the legend remains consistent -  though with a little work that can probably be resolved with manual scales.

Comment: yep. but you shouldn't rely on `gganimate` for that IMO. you should be specifying what you need. that's a personal pref tho.

Answer (score 2):

There's some issue with `gganimate_save`.  In the documentation, under Details, it states:

> If saving to a GIF, uses a custom method that takes advantage of redundant backgrounds (scales, static layers, etc).

In addition to the gif showing both sets of axes, the first image is blank except for the horizontal axes.

If instead you call

```
gganimate(t, "output_test.mp4")
```

Then the resulting movie is as expected.

You can then call imagemagick on the mp4 to convert to gif, in bash (or adapt for a system call from R):

```
> convert output_test.mp4 output_test.gif
```

From R:

```
system('convert output_test.mp4 output_test.gif')
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a quick fix and I have up voted you answer, but it doesn't solve the problem for saving a `.gif` file

Comment: It does create a gif, it just creates a temporary mp4 file first.  ImageMagick is a prerequisite for gganimate anyway.